# Labels are gone in Google Bookmarks

Tags: google-bookmarks

Does anyone use Google Bookmarks?

The instructions on their [support page](http://www.google.com/support/bookmarks/bin/answer.py?answer=171089) says that when we click **Edit** beside the item URL, we can see a way to add Labels; but there isn't any for me.

[image]

I need a solution, definitely lack of tags is making it impossible for me to organize my bookmarks!

Comment: Strange, the _Lables_ field should appear just below the _Name_ field.

Comment: @Alex yea google bookmarks is strange like mad. for one thing if i have my bookmarks in list, i can't export them unless i remove them from the lists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You look to be in the **lists** editing area of Google Bookmarks.

Follow this link;

https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l

To go to the main bookmark area, clicking the edit link here will allow you to add labels.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is weird.. why is it that we can only give tags to bookmarks not in lists?